# Puting a variable next to a input box in a HTML Form

Tags: php, html, arrays

For the following code I keep on getting <'Name'> and then an input box next to it. All I really want the output to be is Name:(input box). The <''> is not needed.

$inputalt is obviously a variable, below is the array that  I am using.

```
     //name values for text input fields
     $inputlist = array("fName" => "First Name", "lName" => "Last Name", "email" => "Email", "phone" => "Phone", "ShoeSize" => "ShoeSize");
```

This is the piece of code I am having trouble with.

```
   <?php
     foreach($inputlist as $inputname => $inputalt){
        if(!isset($$inputname)){
            $$inputname = "";
        }

        echo "<'$inputalt'> <input type='text' name='$inputname' value='" . $$inputname . "'/>";
```

Comment: No problem, I just did, I was trying to do it earlier but stackoverflow requires you wait for a certain amount of time before you check it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes and `<` and `>` symbols.

```
echo "$inputalt <input type='text' name='$inputname' value='$inputname'/>";
```